# test getting skipped in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to use parametrize for which I want to give testcases which I get from a different function using pytest.
I have tried this

```
test_input = []
rarp_input1 = ""
rarp_output1 = ""
count =1
def test_first_rarp():
    global test_input
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(sys.argv[2])
    global rarp_input1
    global rarp_output1
    rarp_input1 = config.get('rarp', 'rarp_input1')
    rarp_input1 =dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(rarp_input1)
    rarp_input2 = config.get('rarp','rarp_input2')
    rarp_output1 = config.getint('rarp','rarp_output1')
    rarp_output2 = config.get('rarp','rarp_output2')
    dict_input = []
    dict_input.append(rarp_input1)
    dict_output = []
    dict_output.append(rarp_output1)
    global count
    test_input.append((dict_input[0],count,dict_output[0]))
    #assert test_input == [something something,someInt]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input1,test_input2,expected1",test_input)
def test_mod_rarp(test_input1,test_input2,expected1):
    global test_input
    assert mod_rarp(test_input1,test_input2) == expected1
```

But the second test case is getting skipped. It says

> test_mod_rarp1.py::test_mod_rarp[test_input10-test_input20-expected10]

Why is the test case getting skipped? I have checked that neither the function nor the input is wrong. Because the following code is working fine

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input1,test_input2,expected1,[something something,someInt,someInt])
def test_mod_rarp(test_input1,test_input2,expected1):
    assert mod_rarp(test_input1,test_input2) == expected1
```

I have not put actual inputs here. Its correct anyway. Also I have config file from which I am taking inputs using configParser. test_mod_rarp1.py is the python file name where I am doing this. I basically want to know if we can access variables(test_input in my example) from other functions to use in parametrize if that is causing problem here. If we can't how do I change the scope of the variable?

Comment: Why are you using globals for this? If you want to write a function to create the test cases, *make it return a new list* with them in. But anyway, you don't appear to be calling it and we've no idea what `mod_rarp` is supposed to do so there's no obvious way to help.

Comment: I thought I would use the variables wherever I want even in other modules without the need of importing this module. Fine then. Returning the required variable and using with prametrize is working perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But still I am curious about the scope of variables. Why was I not able to use test_input with parametrize even though I made it global ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parametrization happens at compile time so that is the reason if you want to parametrized on data generated at run time it skips that.

The ideal way to acheive what you are trying to do is by using fixture parametrization.

Below example should clear things for you and then you could apply the same logic in your case

```
import pytest
input = []

def generate_input():
    global input
    input = [10,20,30]



@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", input)
def test_1(a):
    assert a < 25

def generate_input2():
    return [10, 20, 30]


@pytest.fixture(params=generate_input2())
def a(request):
    return request.param

def test_2(a):
    assert a < 25
```

**OP**

```
<SKIPPED:>pytest_suites/test_sample.py::test_1[a0]


********** test_2[10] **********
<EXECUTING:>pytest_suites/test_sample.py::test_2[10]
Collected Tests
TEST::pytest_suites/test_sample.py::test_1[a0]
TEST::pytest_suites/test_sample.py::test_2[10]
TEST::pytest_suites/test_sample.py::test_2[20]
TEST::pytest_suites/test_sample.py::test_2[30]
```

See `test_1` was skipped  because parameterization happened before execution of `generate_input()` but `test_2` gets parameterized as required